# WebView android/JS

Tags: javascript, android

Я реализую WebView следующим образом:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    private TextView textView;
    private Button btnMyAudio;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);        
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://anika-cs.ru/app/music/index.html");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
       
    }
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            
           /* view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { \" +\n" +
                    "            \"hide('dev_req_run_btn');\"+\n" +
                    "            \"var panel = document.getElementById('dev_const_count');\"+\n" +
                    "            \"panel.style['width'] = '550px';\"+\n" +
                    "            \"function hide(id){if (document.getElementById(id)){document.getElementById(id).style['display'] = 'none';}}\"+\n" +
                    "            \"})()");*/
            injectScriptFile(view, "js/script.js");
        }

        private void injectScriptFile(WebView view, String scriptFile) {
            InputStream input;
            try {
                input = getAssets().open(scriptFile);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
                input.read(buffer);
                input.close();                
                String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {alert('dsdsd');})()");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот мой код html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";

}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<div style="widh:200px;height:200px;background-color:red;" id="block1">
</div>
<div style="widh:200px;height:200px;background-color:gray;">
<button onclick="" id="dev_const_ovner">OK</button>
</div>
    <p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Страницу загружает, но как мне выполнить js, после загрузки страницы??Хотя бы на примере вывода alert диалога? Спасибо.

Comment: Так-то у js есть событие DOMContentLoaded

Answer (score 0):

Без метода инъекции в `onPageFinished`:

```
view.loadUrl(
  "javascript:(function() { " + 
    "var element = document.getElementById('dev_const_owner_id');" + 
    "element.value='185645054';" + 
  "})()"
);
```

Работает.

Comment: Поле ответы предназначено для ответов. Используйте кнопку ["Править"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/616616/edit), чтобы добавить комментарии к своему вопросу, либо оставьте комментарий в соответствующем поле под ответом.

Comment: @Denis, завтра отмечу как правильный.